# how to view all process details from ps –ef command

Tags: linux, process, perl, solaris, ps

I am using the ack.pl in my bash script to search IP's in the Linux OS

only for example , and only to show the problem I will give here a short example

```
   #  ( ./ack.pl -Q -a -l --max-count=1 --ignore-dir=log --ignore-dir=logs --ignore-dir=lib  1.1.1.1 /etc/sysconfig ) &
  [2] 25014
```

in this example I ran the ack.pl to find the IP 1.1.1.1 under /etc/sysconfig

but when I try to see the process details as the following

```
     # ps -ef | grep  25014

       root 25014 13283   1 14:46:53 pts/1       0:06 perl ./ack.pl -Q -a -l --max-count=1 --ignore-dir=log --ignore-dir=logs --ignor
```

then I am not able to see the "/etc/sysconfig" in the proccess?

my question is:

what I need to do in order to see the PATH - /etc/syscconfig in the process that opened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the path in Solaris you need to run this command.

```
printf "%s\n" $(readlink /proc/<PID>/path/a.out)
```

Replace `<PID>` with the required process id.

Example:

```
printf "%s\n" $(readlink /proc/25014/path/a.out)
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/is-it-possible-to-find-the-path-of-a-running-program)

Comment: I am using solaris , I not see any exe folder after the proccess ID dir

Comment: You didn't mentioned Solaris once in your question. Anyways I am not that familiar with Solaris but I managed to figure out the path of the running process. So I am editing my answer, please take a look at it and tell me if it works.

Comment: You should also edit your question and tag it appropriately so that people who can really help you with it can notice it.

Comment: DONE - I edit this question

Comment: Did the command worked?

Comment: I get this --> printf "%s\n" $(readlink /proc/2404/path/a.out)
-bash: readlink: command not found

Comment: Try ls in place of readlink then.

Comment: now I get -->  printf "%s\n" $( ls /proc/16232/path/a.out)
Illegal variable name.

Comment: No I mean use only ls -la /proc/16232/path/a.out

Comment: I get this --> ls -la /proc/18592/path/a.out
/proc/18592/path/a.out: No such file or directory

Comment: I am sorry I can't help you with this. I am not that familiar with Solaris. But the command I mentioned previously works for Linux.